# Wire collection of objects dynamically in Guice

Tags: java, playframework, guice

Guice newbie here, with a complicated scenario.

My company has a large number of constants of a given type (let's call them `Thingy`) that belong to different teams and are maintained in different parts of our application. However, we need to have a central registry that knows about all of them (let's call this the `ThingyService`). I am writing a base module that teams can either extend or install, with the purpose of allowing a team to register their `Thingy`s, and giving them access to the `ThingyService`. This module takes as parameter a list of classes from which I can extract the `Thingy` constants, this part is working fine.

What I don't understand is how I can a) make each module know about each other module's list of `Thingy`s and b) how I can create my `ThingyService` as a singleton that contains all of my `Thingy`s. I have experimented with shared static state and with ThreadLocals, but I keep either breaking tests or breaking my main (play) application. In my naive understanding of Guice, I think I need a `MultiBinder` for the `Thingy`s, but I don't see how I can share that between modules. Here's what I'd like to do:

```
class ThingyModule extends AbstractModule{
   final Set<Class<?>> myThingyClasses; // this is populated in the constructor

   private Set<Thingy> extractThingiesFromThingyClasses(){
      // I have this working
   }

   @Provides @Singleton ThingyService thingyService(
       Set<Thingy> thingys // all thingys, from all such modules
   ){
       return new ThingyService(thingys);
   }

   protected void configure(){
       extractThingiesFromThingyClasses().forEach(thingy->
           // bind thingy to a global MultiBinder?
       );
   }
}
```

How can I make my `ThingyService` unique and global, with all the `Thingy`s from the entire application? Note: I don't necessarily need my `Thingy`s to be managed by Guice, the only place I need them is in `ThingyService`. Also, this is a play / scala application if that makes a difference, but my `ThingyModule` code lives in a library written in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I omitted one important detail, `Thingy` has a type parameter, it's actually `Thingy<T>`, and that's the reason it didn't work before. By cheating and registering Thingy as raw type, and then also injecting it as raw type, I got it to work.

Here is a complete working example using JUnit 5 and AssertJ:

```
class ThingyModuleTest {

    static class Thingy<T>{
        private final T value;
        Thingy(final T value) {this.value = value;}
        @Override public boolean equals(final Object o) {
            if (this == o) { return true; }
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) { return false; }
            final Thingy<?> thingy = (Thingy<?>) o; return Objects.equals(value, thingy.value); }
        @Override public int hashCode() { return Objects.hash(value); }
    }

    @Singleton
    static class ThingyService{
        final Set<Thingy<?>> thingies;
        @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"}) @Inject
        ThingyService(Set<Thingy> thingies) {
            this.thingies = ImmutableSet.copyOf((Set)thingies);
        }
        public Set<Thingy<?>> getThingies() { return thingies; }
    }

    abstract static class ThingyModule extends AbstractModule {
        private final Set<Class<?>> classesToScan;
        public ThingyModule(Class<?>... classes) {
            this.classesToScan = ImmutableSet.copyOf(classes);
        }

        private Set<Thingy<?>> scanForThingies(){
                return classesToScan.stream()
                         .flatMap(c-> Arrays.stream(c.getDeclaredFields()))
                         .filter(f->f.getType().isAssignableFrom(Thingy.class))
                         .filter(f-> Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())&&Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()))
                         .map(this::readThingy)
                         .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                         .map(Optional::get)
                         .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        private Optional<Thingy<?>> readThingy(final Field field) {
            try{
                field.setAccessible(true);
                return Optional.ofNullable(field.get(null))
                    .filter(Thingy.class::isInstance)
                    .map(Thingy.class::cast);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) { return Optional.empty(); }
        }

        @Override protected void configure() {
            bind(ThingyService.class);
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Multibinder<Thingy> multibinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), Thingy.class);
            scanForThingies().forEach(thingy -> multibinder.addBinding().toInstance(thingy));
        }
    }

    static class ThingyModule1 extends ThingyModule {
        public ThingyModule1() { super(Thingies1.class); }
        static class Thingies1{
            static final Thingy<Boolean> BooleanThingy = new Thingy<>(true);
            static final Thingy<Integer> IntThingy = new Thingy<>(123);
        }
    }

    static class ThingyModule2 extends ThingyModule {
        public ThingyModule2() { super(Thingies2.class); }
        static class Thingies2{
            static final Thingy<String> StringThingy = new Thingy<>("hello");
            static final Thingy<Long> LongThingy = new Thingy<>(123L);
        }
    }

    @Test void validateThingyService() {
        ThingyService thingyService = Guice.createInjector(new ThingyModule1(), new ThingyModule2())
                                           .getProvider(ThingyService.class)
                                           .get();
        assertThat(thingyService).isNotNull()
                                 .extracting(ts -> ImmutableList.copyOf(ts.getThingies()))
                                 .asList()
                                 .containsExactlyInAnyOrder(BooleanThingy, IntThingy, StringThingy, LongThingy);
    }
}
```

I will mark this answer as accepted until somebody else provides a more idiomatic one.